# Condition before insert SQL

Tags: sql, db2

In DB2 SQL, I want to write something like

```
insert into employees 
  (id, name) values (1, "emp1")
  where (select count(*) from employee_registry) <= 10
```

Can't figure out the correct syntax though.

---

post edit.

i wanted to insert records only if some condition is met.

Comment: What you've written makes zero sense. Please [edit] your question to explain specifically (in plain words, not SQL) what you're trying to do.

Comment: `select count(*) from employee_registry` will give you one number regardless of the contents of the `employee` table.  Is there some link between the two tables that you are missing?

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a `SELECT` statement somewhere in order to use the `WHERE` clause, so something like this might work:

```
insert into employees (id, name) 
select 1, 'emp1' from sysibm.sysdummy1
where (select count(*) from employee_registry) <= 10
```

`sysibm.sysdummy1` is a special system table that always has only one row.

Answer (score 0):

Other method, group by Nothing + having :

```
insert into employees (id, name)
select '1', 'emp1' from employee_registry
group by 1 having count(*)<=10
```